# В профиле слетел перевод строк

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Newest:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- All actions.
- Responses.
- Bounties.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Recent.
- Class.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Votes cast
- Active
- Offered
- Earned

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё парочка:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Держи ещё: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxieb.png

Comment: Хм.. Не знал, что мета отдельно считает дни и влияние: на прошлом скрине было с меты, а это с основного сайта: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy5Z1.png

Comment: @Qwertiy можно иметь акк на основном сайте, но не иметь на мете.

Comment: Разве сошлись не на том, что это последствия кривого удаления?

Comment: @Qwertiy не уверен, не помню уже )

Comment: @Qwertiy на SOen тоже самое.

Comment: @Qwertiy иметь аккаунт и посещать - это всё же разное. Можно не ходить на мету, тогда по ней дней не будет. Так же и с влиянием, оно ведь по просмотрам сообщений оценивается. Сообщений именно указанного сайта (а не в паре основной + мета). Поэтому и счётчики разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы добавил/утвердил всё из вышеперечисленного.

Ждите на сайте после подкачки/пересборки.

Переводы можно проверить/предложить для улучшения на https://ru.traducir.win/

Comment: Мне показалось или кто-то поменял? "Edit profile and settings" переведено просто как "Править".

Comment: @Suvitruf почему-то [откатилось](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/170804331?q=key%3A69266bcdb5b1ae711ad949b1f8f058fd). Не знаю точно, можно ли как-то выяснить на каком этапе и кем.

Comment: @Suvitruf опять стало "Править". И с этим традусёром и не поймёшь толком кто меняет.

Comment: Вариантов не то, чтобы много)

Comment: @Suvitruf ну, парочка точно есть. Сладкая. Собственно, нашёлся [автор](https://ru.traducir.win/suggestions/6).